# How to search in an Object with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, nspredicate

In an Nsarray i need to filter all elements containing a searchKey (eg 39013) . For now, it is returning wrong values. What is wrong with my searching function? I think the problem is at the FORMAT line but couldn't figure out what to do?

**requirement**: Searchbar must search the values in DesenNo which declared in LocationModel object.

Here is the object

```
import UIKit

class LocationModel: NSObject {
    //properties
    var DesenNo: String?
    var Dolar: String?
    var Zemin: String?
    var En: String?
    var Euro: String?
    var Renk: String?
}
```

And this is my searching function:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.isActive {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "LocationModel.DesenNo CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        let array = self.feedItems.filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: ($0 as! LocationModel).DesenNo) }

        let filterArray = array.map {($0 as! LocationModel).DesenNo}
        filteredData = filterArray as! [String]
        listTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSPredicate`? Just use a standard Swift array `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a predicate. Just use a simple Swift array filter:

Assuming `self.feedItems` is declared as `[LocationModel]`, you just need:

```
let matchingModels = self.feedItems.filter { $0.DesenNo?.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }
```

If you then want those results reduced to just the list of corresponding `DesenNo` values, do:

```
filteredData = matchingModels.map { $0.DesenNo }
```

As a side note, there is no need for your `LocationModel` class to extend `NSObject`. It should also be a `struct`, not a `class`.

Also note that it is standard practice that variable and method names start with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.isActive {    
        let matchingModels = self.feedItems.filter { $0.DesenNo?.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }
        filteredData = matchingModels.map { $0.DesenNo }

        listTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If you really want to use `NSPredicate` for some reason, you can update your code to:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.isActive {
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "DesenNo CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        let array = self.feedItems.filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
        filteredData = array.map { $0.DesenNo }

        listTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        filteredData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        listTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

If `self.feedItems` is actually an `NSArray` instead of a proper Swift array, change:

```
... = self.feedItems.filter { ...
```

to:

```
... = (self.feedItems as! [LocationModel]).filter { ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response @rmaddy . But there is a little problem. feedItems is declared as Nsarray. So when i updated my function with yours, i get error ***Value of type 'Any' has no member 'DesenNo'"***

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` or other Objective-C collections in your Swift code. Change it to a proper Swift array and make your coding cleaner, safer, and easier to read.

Comment: It will be really hard and will take a long time, i am just focused on the searchbar for now. I also edited the question and added the main viewcontroller. Can you check it out and give me a helping hand? I am really stuck here, i will be really grateful!! Thank you @rmaddy

Comment: See the bit I just added to the end of my answer to help with the `NSArray` usage. And changing that `NSArray` to a Swift array now will save you far more time down the road.

Comment: You are a great helper! I was stuck in this for a looooooong time. I feel like i am really close to solution. There is one more little problem .
***            let array = (self.feedItems as! [LocationModel]).filter { searchPredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
            filteredData = array.map { $0.DesenNo! }***

Comment: That's odd because `array` should now be a Swift array. Try the same change: `filteredData = (array as! [LocationModel]).map { $0.DesnNo }`.

Comment: And again, you are wasting a lot of this time because of using `NSArray`. Fixing it sooner than later would be saving you all of this time.

Comment: You are right! I have to fix it to swift array. But i changed the codes that you advice, now the app freeze and i get error **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Comment: I can't help with information. Fix the array. It will truly be faster than providing any more hacks to work around the misuse of `NSArray`.

Comment: Thank you man! I'm so grateful. I will be working with your advices. Have a great day.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate an answer solved your issues by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.